Where can a tourist get a yellow fever vaccination in Morocco?
I would like to know if a tourist can get a yellow fever vaccination in Morocco? And if so, how easy / difficult will this be?
What I have tried

I found the Institut Pasteur du Maroc. They do mention yellow fever. But can a tourist go there and get vaccinated?
Searched for "travel clinic" using google maps. A lot of clinics come up. Not sure if any of them will give a tourist a yellow fever vaccine.

e.g. https://www.google.com/maps/search/clinique+du+voyage+tangier+maroc/@35.787214,-5.8379305,13.61z?entry=ttu



My questions

General: is it possible for a tourist to get a yellow fever vaccine in Morocco?
Specific: where in Morocco can I get a yellow fever vaccine?

(I've never been to Morocco and I am not in Morocco at the moment.)

How about you email them and ask. Share the answer if you get any.

Try to do where you are living now. You may need two yellow fever vaccinations and a short waiting period before protection is recognized (by some countries).

According to the UK's NHS, yellow fever vaccination needs to be given 10 days before travel to be effective, so even if you can get it in Morocco, it may not be much use there.


I found the Institut Pasteur du Maroc. They do mention yellow fever. But can a tourist go there and get vaccinated?

Yes.

Your one-word answer would be improved by offering some evidence for why it is correct.
